# Symfony feature to take screenshots of pages that require user to login

Tags: symfony

I have an app built with Symfony 2. It has a bunch of pages that are secured and require user to login. Once the user is logged in I want there to be a "Download Screenshots" Button. When they click that button, I would like a process to go through all the pages of the site and take screenshots. What tool should I use to take the screenshots? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this so I can't speak for how well it works, but check out https://github.com/microweber/screen